# Writing a script to print a string between two patterns using regex, but the last occurrence only

Tags: python, regex, linux, raspberry-pi3

I'm writing a python script on my Raspberry Pi 3 that will record weights from a open source scale and place them in a database.  The scale simply records the output/readings to a file. The problem is the scale outputs a lot of data that I don't need. And each time the script runs it adds a new readout to the bottom of the file, which you can see a portion of below.  So basically what I need is the most recent weight reading which will always be on the last line of the file.

I'm kind of terrible at regex.  And despite my searching and trying I can't seem to isolate just the last weight reading.

```
Serial Load Cell Converter version 1.2
By SparkFun Electronics
No remote sensor found
Minimum time between reports: 791
Press x to bring up settings
Readings:
1274,2.5007,lbs,540611,

Serial Load Cell Converter version 1.2
By SparkFun Electronics
No remote sensor found
Minimum time between reports: 792
Press x to bring up settings
Readings:
1341,2.5008,lbs,540620,

Serial Load Cell Converter version 1.2
By SparkFun Electronics
No remote sensor found
Minimum time between reports: 792
Press x to bring up settings
Readings:
1321,2.5009,lbs,540643,
```

Last line:
    1321,2.5009,lbs,540643,

I need the value where "2.5009" is, but I can't simply match that number because it can change drastically with each added readout, as do the other numbers on the last line.  The only things that stay constant are the commas and the "lbs".

Comment: So, your expected output is: values between "Readings:
1321" and ",lbs"?

Comment: That's right.  But as I said, the 1321 will change with each reading and only the commas and lbs will be constant

Comment: So I'm looking for the value at the hash marks:

Comment: I'm looking for the decimal value at the hash marks: 1321,#######,lbs,540643,

Comment: Try `(?s)^.*,(\d+(?:\.\d+)),lbs\b` https://regex101.com/r/ddIbOa/1

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, this expression might extract the last value:

```
.*Readings:\s*[^,]*,\s*([^,]*?)\s*,
```

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r".*Readings:\s*[^,]*,\s*([^,]*?)\s*,"

test_str = """
Serial Load Cell Converter version 1.2
By SparkFun Electronics
No remote sensor found
Minimum time between reports: 791
Press x to bring up settings
Readings:
1274,2.5007,lbs,540611,

Serial Load Cell Converter version 1.2
By SparkFun Electronics
No remote sensor found
Minimum time between reports: 792
Press x to bring up settings
Readings:
1341,2.5008 ,lbs,540620,

Serial Load Cell Converter version 1.2
By SparkFun Electronics
No remote sensor found
Minimum time between reports: 792
Press x to bring up settings
Readings:
1321, 2.5009,lbs,540643,

"""

print(re.findall(regex, test_str, re.DOTALL))
```

#### Output

```
['2.5009']
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/txo5qF/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/txo5qF/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: Thanks Emma. But I was trying to get only get the last weight reading "2.5009" which will always be on the last line of the file, if that helps.